# How to delete part-Frag file?

Tags: delete, undelete

When I want to delete this file it shows an error like this:

[image]

How to fix this error and delete that file?

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -lbAF ~/Desktop`?

Comment: My problem is solved. I just need to reboot my laptop

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use inode number to delete this file:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ ls -i *Frag829
27526975  your long file name would be here  ....
```

then use `find` to remove it:

```
$ find ~/Desktop -maxdepth 1 -inum 27526975
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is solved. I just need to reboot my laptop